# SQL logical groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table called 'items' (say this is a shopping list):

**Types**: 1. meat, 2. fruit, 3. veg

```
+----+----------+------+
| id |   item   | type |
+----+----------+------+
|  1 | chicken  |    1 |
|  2 | orange   |    2 |
|  3 | apple    |    2 |
|  4 | beef     |    1 |
|  5 | potatoes |    3 |
|  6 | lamb     |    1 |
|  7 | tomatoes |    3 |
|  8 | cucumber |    3 |
|  9 | pork     |    1 |
| 10 | pear     |    2 |
| 11 | beans    |    3 |
+----+----------+------+
```

And I would like to get the following logical table:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+-----+------+-------+-------------------+
| only veg | only meat | only fruit | veg | meat | fruit | only meat & fruit |
+----------+-----------+------------+-----+------+-------+-------------------+
|        0 |         0 |          0 |   1 |    1 |     1 |                 0 |
+----------+-----------+------------+-----+------+-------+-------------------+
```

Logic:

- Do I only have vegetables in my list? No. Then, only veg = 0
- Do I only have meat in my shopping list? No. Then, only meat = 0
- Do I only have fruit in my shopping list? No. Then, only fruit = 0
- Do I have vegetables in my shopping list? Yes. Then, veg = 1
- Do I have meat in my shopping list? Yes. Then, Then, meat = 1
- Do I have fruit in my shopping list? Yes. Then, fruit = 1
- Do I only have meat and fruit in my shopping list? No. Then only meat & fruit = 0

Another example:

```
+----+---------+------+
| id |  item   | type |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 | chicken |    1 |
|  2 | orange  |    2 |
|  3 | apple   |    2 |
|  4 | beef    |    1 |
+----+---------+------+
```

Result:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+-----+------+-------+-------------------+
| only veg | only meat | only fruit | veg | meat | fruit | only meat & fruit |
+----------+-----------+------------+-----+------+-------+-------------------+
|        0 |         0 |          0 |   0 |    1 |     1 |                 1 |
+----------+-----------+------------+-----+------+-------+-------------------+
```

Could anybody help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the numbers in the result?

Comment: More importantly, are tomatoes a vegetable or a fruit?

Comment: @bluefeet, oops, sorry about that. I have another column with the type. I'm going to amend it.

Comment: I would infer them by context. And i'm appalled, tomatoes are classified as a vegetable!

Comment: Actually, chicken is not a meat but rather poultry. Your categories are not good

Comment: @bluefeet, I've now added the types. Thanks.

Comment: @cornell I'm still not fully getting the logic that you are using to get the final result, can you clarify what you need?

Comment: @Tobb - but cucumbers OK?

Comment: @Strawberry had to google it, but no :p Good thing bananas aren't there as a fruit :p

Comment: @Tobb - so I guess strawberrries don't cut it either :-)

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

The following is somewhat similar to [@Tobb's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21536696/297408) but with this method the table is scanned just once:

```
SELECT
  MIN(CASE type WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS meat_only,
  MIN(CASE type WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS fruit_only,
  MIN(CASE type WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS veg_only,

  MAX(CASE type WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS meat,
  MAX(CASE type WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS fruit,
  MAX(CASE type WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS veg,

  MIN(CASE type WHEN 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS meat_and_fruit_only
FROM items
;
```

The query uses conditional aggregation (meaning the argument of an aggregate function is a conditional expression, more specifically a CASE expression) to calculate the results.

In case you aren't yet familiar with conditional aggregation, there's not much difference between `AGG(CASE ... END)` and `AGG(column)`. In both cases the argument is a column of values, only in the first case the column is one that's calculated at runtime with a CASE expression.

It might be easier to understand the method if you start with a query like this:

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE type WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_meat,
  CASE type WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_fruit,
  CASE type WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_veg
FROM items
;
```

You can see the same CASE expressions here as used in the first query, only this time they are returned as normal, non-aggregated columns of values. This is what the output would look like for the first data sample in your question:

```
id  item      type  is_meat  is_fruit  is_veg
--  --------  ----  -------  --------  ------
 1  chicken      1        1         0       0
 2  orange       2        0         1       0
 3  apple        2        0         1       0
 4  beef         1        1         0       0
 5  potatoes     3        0         0       1
 6  lamb         1        1         0       0
 7  tomatoes     3        0         0       1
 8  cucumber     3        0         0       1
 9  pork         1        1         0       0
10  pear         2        0         1       0
11  beans        3        0         0       1
```

Based on the above output, the logic of the first query might be easier understood. For instance, `meat_only` should be 1 if all `is_meat` values in the second query are 1, otherwise it should be 0. In other words, if there's at least one `is_meat = 0` row, the `only_meat` value should be 0 too. Therefore, in implementing the `meat_only` logic, we are essentially going for the lowest `is_meat` value – hence the use of `MIN`. Same applies for the other two `*_only` results.

The logic behind the `meat` result could be viewed as the opposite of the previous one: if there's at least one 1 in the `is_meat` column, the result should be 1 too, otherwise (meaning, "if *all* values are 0") it should be 0. So, we are going for the greatest `is_meat` value now – that's why we are using `MAX` for `meat`, as well as `fruit` and `veg`.

The last result, `meat_and_fruit_only` is a little bit different in that it does not use the "only meat & fruit" logic directly but instead uses the complementary logic of "no vegetables". I only chose to do so to match the simple CASE syntax of the previous expressions and, of course, it was possible only due to the fact that there are only three types of items. With more types you might probably prefer to implement the logic directly as specified, for which it would be better to use the searched CASE syntax instead of the simple CASE one:

```
MIN(CASE WHEN type IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS meat_and_fruit_only
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select    
    ifnull((select max(0) from Items where type <> 3), 1) as "only veg",
    ifnull((select max(0) from Items where type <> 1), 1) as "only meat",
    ifnull((select max(0) from Items where type <> 2), 1) as "only fruit",
    ifnull((select max(1) from Items where type = 3), 0) as "veg",
    ifnull((select max(1) from Items where type = 1), 0) as "meat",
    ifnull((select max(1) from Items where type = 2), 0) as "fruit",
    ifnull((select max(0) from Items where type = 3), 1) as "only meat and fruit"
from (select 1) as p
```

Here is my solution. You can try it yourself by pasting it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5be90

It's written with MySQL dialect, if you use something else you might have to exchange the `ifnull`s with `isnull`.

To break it down a bit:

This query uses multiple nested selects to build the table, but lets first look at the from clause. Without the nested selects (with `*` instead), this query would return a 1 row 1 column result, containing just a 1. It doesn't really matter, because the outer `from`-clause is not being used for anything, all it needs to do is return 1 row.

Then, looking at the nested selects:

```
(select max(0) from Items where type <> 3)
```

This select checks if there is are only vegetables, by trying to find a row that is something different than a vegetable. If we do find such a row, then it's not all vegetables, so we return a `0` (the `max` thing is just to make sure we get just 1 row.) If there are no rows with a type other than 3, it will return `null`.

The second step is then to handle the `null`-value. If we get a `null`, then we know that there are no rows with a type different than 3, and thus the rows must all be vegetables. The `ifnull` works like this:

```
ifnull(<some value>, 1)
```

Which means that if `<some value>` is null, it will return 1 (the second parameter to the function), if its not it will return `<some value>`. So,

```
ifnull((select max(0) from Items where type <> 3), 1)
```

So, if we find something that is not a vegetable, the inner select will return `0`, and so will the `ifnull` function. If the inner select returns `null` on the other hand, the rows are all vegetables, so `1` should be the final value, and that's what the `ifnull`-function returns.

The second case is finding if there are any vegetables:

```
ifnull((select max(1) from Items where type = 3), 0)
```

Here it's the other way around basically, the inner select returns `1` if we find at least one row that's a vegetable, `null` if we don't. Since `null` in this case means that there are no vegetables, the `ifnull` should return `0`.

I'll leave the last one to figure out yourself.